# Can't get QT 5.1.1 working on OS X 10.6.8

Tags: c++, macos, qt

**Update**
I thought the problem may have to do with the fact that the installer was trying to unpack the different frameworks into `/Users/bld.qt` (with the `/Users` directory being write protected), so I tried to create `/Users/bld.qt` and gave everyone write privileges. However, this didn't work as the installer didn't write anything to this folder and the errors still occured.

**System Info**
I am running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and I have XCode 3.2.5 installed.
Running `which gcc` outputs `/usr/bin/gcc`
Running `which clang` outputs `/usr/bin/clang`

**What I've Tried**
I've tried installing qt using both the offline and online installers:

> qt-mac-opensource-1.4.0-2-x86_64-online.dmg
>   qt-mac-opensource-5.1.1-clang-offline.dmg

However in the middle of `Installing component Essential modules`, both of these give me the following errors (no matter how many times I hit `Retry`):

```
Error during installation process (qt.511.clang_64.essentials):
Command install_name_tool failed.
Arguments: -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtQuickTest.framework/Versions/5/QtQuickTest /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtQuickTest.framework/Versions/5/QtQuickTest -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/bin/qmltestrunner
Output:
```

And during `Installing component Add-On modules`, I get the errors:

```
Error during installation process (qt.511.clang_64.addons):
Command install_name_tool failed.
Arguments: -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtQuickTest.framework/Versions/5/QtQuickTest /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtQuickTest.framework/Versions/5/QtQuickTest -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml -change /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork /usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/bin/qmltestrunner
Output:
```

After hitting `Ignore` on both, the installation continues fine, but then I try using Qt Creator and get the following message under Preferences: `Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install`

[image: Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install]

After installation, running `which qmake` outputs `/usr/local/qt/5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/bin/qmake`

Comment: So is `clang` installed?

Comment: Have you tried a different version, e.g. 4.8.?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, `which clang` gives `/usr/bin/clang`. @fiscblog I'll try installing 4.8 and see what happens.

Comment: And it looks like you are running Snow Leopard; are you sure that version of Qt supports Snow Leopard (the new `libc++.dylib` is installed on Lion+ and it might be using that)?

Comment: I strongly suspect your compiler/system is too old for Qt 5.1.1.  You could try installing Xcode 4.2 (the last Xcode 4 to support Snow Leopard) and install the Xcode command line package.  If you find that the pre-packaged Qt does not work for you then you can probably install it via Macports.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of Xcode that supports Snow Leopard and the Xcode command line package.  I suspect updating your tool set is what's necessary.  However, disk permission can get screwy in OS X from time to time making reads/writes fail.  Go into Disk Utility and repair your disk permissions before you try again.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 4.2 is the most up to date IDE on OS X 10.6.8
I built Qt 5.1.1 and Qt Creator 2.8.1 for Android development.
The building is fine. But it cannot deploy automatically.